# Unable To Overload != Operator Due To Error 3 requires a matching operator?

Tags: c#, .net

> Unable To Overload != , Error 3 The operator
>   'ConsoleApplication13.pl.operator !=(ConsoleApplication13.pl,
>   ConsoleApplication13.pl)' requires a matching operator '==' to also be
>   defined C:\Users\htg\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication13\ConsoleApplication13\Program.cs 37
>   28 ConsoleApplication13 .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        pl a ,b,c;
       a= new pl();
        b=new pl();
        a.mark=99;
        b.mark=10;
        c = a+b;
        if (c != b)
            Console.WriteLine("is not equal");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("both are equal");
        Console.WriteLine(c.mark);
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class pl
{
    public int mark;
    public static pl operator+ ( pl a , pl b) // 1. here It Work's Perfectly At + overloading
    {
        pl mm = new pl();
        mm.mark = a.mark + b.mark;
        return mm;

    }
    public static bool operator!= (pl m , pl n) // 2. unable to overload
    {
        if (m.mark != n.mark)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }       
}
```

Comment: When overloading `!=` you *have to overload* `==` as well; it's highly recommended to overload `Equals()` and `GetHashcode()` in addition

Comment: As an aside, I'd *strongly* urge you to avoid public fields, and to put more effort into using meaningful and conventional names.

Comment: Read the error message, please. It _very clearly_ states that operator!= "requires a matching operator '==' to also be defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - C# requires that if you overload the `!=` operator, you also overload the `==` operator. From the C# 5 specification, section 10.10.2:

> Certain binary operators require pair-wise declaration. For every declaration of either operator of a pair, there must be a matching declaration of the other operator of the pair. Two operator declarations match when they have the same return type and the same type for each parameter. The following operators require pair-wise declaration:
>
> - operator `==` and operator `!=`
> - operator `>` and operator `<`
> - operator `>=` and operator `<=`

In this case, it looks like you want:

```
public static bool operator ==(pl m, pl n)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(m, n))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(m, null) || ReferenceEquals(n, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return m.mark == n.mark;
}    

public static bool operator !=(pl m, pl n)
{
     return !(m == n);
}
```

Note how `!=` is implemented in terms of `==` - this is almost *always* the simplest approach to implementing these operators. Implement `==` fully as it's easier to think in terms of positives, and then implement `!=` as the inverse. The `ReferenceEquals` checks are performed to mean that `null == null` is true, but anything non-null is not equal to null. (This is also a common optimization to ensure that `x == x` is true without performing any further tests.)

As noted in comments, it's also very unusual to overload `==` and `!=` without *also* overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals(object)`; I'd also recommend implementing `IEquatable<T>`. You should implement those to be compatible with your `==` operator - the `GetHashCode` method would probably be best just returning `mark`.

Comment: `return m.mark == n.mark;` in the `==` operator is not enough, what if `n` or `m` or both are `null`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: True, was only going by the original implementation. Will fix.

Comment: yes but why we need to overload both != As well as == or vice versa , see when you are overloading (a!=b) , it will give you result that's it than again why we need to check for(a==b) And It Does Not Make Any Sense

Comment: @vivek: You need to overload them both because it would be *really* confusing to only overload one. I'm afraid I couldn't understand your comment of "see when you are overloading (a!=b) , it will give you result that's it than again why we need to check for(a==b)". If you're asking why the compiler doesn't automatically provide the other overload - that would be possible in some cases, but not in others. (It's possible to overload those operators not to return `bool`, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

When implementing `!=` you *have to* implement `==` as well; it's highly recommended to override both `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```
  class pl {
    public int mark;

    ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
      pl other = obj as pl;

      return Object.ReferenceEquals(null, other) ? false : mark == other.mark;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
      return mark;
    }

    public static Boolean operator ==(pl left, pl right) {
      // what if left or right or both are null?
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        return true;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        return false;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, right))
        return false;

      return left.mark == right.mark;
    }

    public static Boolean operator !=(pl left, pl right) {
      return ! (left == right);
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes but why we need to overload both != As well as == or vice versa , see when you are overloading (a!=b) , it will give you result that's it than again why we need to check for(a==b) And It Does Not Make Any Sense